# Self Host Web Api Unit Test With Area

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, vs-unit-testing-framework, self-hosting

I'm following some tutorials about creating a HttpSelfHostServer to test my Web Api.  The issue I'm having is that my core API is inside an area and I cannot get my routes registered correctly.

Anyone have a good tutorial or sample code to get this working with an Area specifically?

Comment: I was under the impression that Areas don't work with Web API.

Comment: My areas work fine, I can't seem to test them when trying to Self Host and unit test them.

Comment: Are you sure?  According to this article http://netmvc.blogspot.be/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-4-webapi-support-areas-in.html you need to implement a custom controller selector.

Comment: I'm positive.  I can access my area no problem when not using a self hosted http server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by moving the routes that were inside my AreaRegistration down into the core WebApiConfig where the main routes are usually defined.